# to get Vs. getting in the following context

Tags: grammar

I've written a message, and inside it, I put the following sentence:

> "I don't have a problem **to get** even more than 5 people, I have enough room".

My spell checker immediately indicated a problem with "to get" and suggested **writing** (here also: not to write) "**getting**" in the mentioned sentence.

> "I don't have a problem getting even more than 5 people, I have enough room".

I have no idea if it is correct or not.
(If it is correct, then I'd like to get a reference for learning about this topic which I am not familiar with yet.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are really saying here is:

> "I don't have a problem **with** getting even more than 5 people"

In conversation, people would still understand you if you dropped the "with", though technically this changes the meaning.

You would never say:

> "I don't have a problem **with to get** even more than 5 people"

You may wish to search this site for other answers and explanations relating to the use of "infinitive Vs gerund".

Comment: With your explanation about the invisible sentence: "I don't have a problem **with** getting even more than 5 people", You made it quickly very understandable to me! Thank you.